# clicking only one legend at a time: ChartJS

Tags: onclick, chart.js, legend, chartjs-2.6.0

i would like to know a way by which i can get to click only one legend at a time, to be precise i want one legend (if its clicked) to get unclicked when the other one is clicked in chartJS donut chart, there are only 2 legends